# Pagina Perfil não aparece SOPT

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, beta

Sempre utilizei minha página do perfil para acessar os outros site do SE, porém a página do SOPT não aparece lá.

Porque na página do meu perfil não aparece nas minhas contas a conta do SOPT? Porque é beta ainda?

Qual seria a maneira mais fácil e rápida de acessar o SOPT dentro dos outros site do SE?

Answer (score 5):

O jeito de acessar mais rápido é pela barra no topo da página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ah! Ontem isso não aparecia pra mim, agora aparece! Deve ter a ver com o novo status "beta" na Area51. Na busca por sites desse mesmo dropdown, o SOPT não aparecia também, agora aparece.

Comment: E acho que entra no perfil na lista de Accounts quando for p/ o beta público, senão é bug mesmo.